# Como cerrar automáticamente el mensaje bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy usando bootstrap 3 para mostrar mensajes, quisiera saber como podría cerrar de manera automática el mensaje. mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Cerrar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  El registro ha sido guardado exitosamente!
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías cerrar el mensaje con JQuery. El siguiente código muestra como cerrarlo después de 5 segundos, pero tu puedes modificarlo si así lo deseas:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  El registro ha sido guardado exitosamente!
</div>
Contenido de mi página web
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
}, 5000);


</script>
```

Comment: genial, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: @Dev001 te sugerimos evitar realizar votación entre las mismas cuentas, recuerda que esto no es permitido en el sitio, Te sugerimos revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange