# ¿Hay alguna forma de verificar si existe un valor en un button con js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Hay alguna forma de verificar si existe la propiedad en un button? como por ejemplo disabled="false", en caso de que no exista dejar el button desactivado con disabled="true" mediante JavaScript.

EDIT: Como me pedís el código, pondré el código del botón porque otro código no tengo ya que mi duda va sobre como se puede hacer algo así..

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" disabled="true">Enviar</button>
```

Básicamente la propiedad **disabled** por defecto esta en **false** es decir siempre activado, mi duda es si se puede de alguna manera revisar la propiedad disabled del botón y si no esta en el valor indicado pues darle otro valor, que sería básicamente entre **true/false**, espero que ahora esté mejor explicado, aunque anteriormente también fui preciso pero bueno .. no entiendo a que viene tantas pegas..

Comment: Por favor, añade el codigo con el que estas trabajando para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Ante todo, mejor si explicas qué es exactamente lo que estás intentando hacer, porque no le encuentro mucho sentido a tu consulta.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Hola Catalin, varias de las preguntas que haz realizado no han tenido la aceptación deseada, es muy importante realizar las preguntas en base a a [ask], agregando lo que intentaste o investigaste, de esta forma obtendrás muy buenas respuestas por parte de la comunidad, saludos!.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando javascript puedes seleccionar el elemento que quieras y verificar su propiedad `disabled`. Si la propiedad es `true` entonces el elemento está inhabilitado, si la propiedad es `false`, el elemento está activo. En caso que la propiedad no sea explícitamente declarada, tomará el valor de false, es decir, el elemento está activo por defecto.

Puedes consultar y modificar esta propiedad dependiendo de los requerimientos de tu aplicación. Te adjunto un ejemplo funcional.

He declarado 3 botones, uno habilitado, otro desabilitado y uno que al inicio está habilitado, pero que con javascript se modificará su valor.

He seleccionado los dos primeros elementos utilizando su id, y he impreso su valor por consola. Finalmente te muestro como es posible modificar el tercer botón sobrescribiendo la propiedad `disabled`.

Puedes consultar la documentación de esta propiedad en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled)

```js
const valor1 = document.getElementById("boton1").disabled;
const valor2 = document.getElementById("boton2").disabled;
document.getElementById("boton3").disabled = true

console.log('Estado del boton 1: ', valor1)
console.log('Estado del boton 2: ', valor2)
```

```html
<button id="boton1"> Activado </button>
<button id="boton2" disabled> Desactivado </button>
<button id="boton3"> Me desactivaron </button>
```

Podrías lograr lo mismo utilizando JQuery. Para ello seleccionas elemento y consultas su propiedad a través del método prop especificando la propiedad deseada. En el caso que quieras establecer el valor de la propiedad, agrega un segundo argumento.

```js
const valor1 = $("#boton1").prop("disabled")
const valor2 = $("#boton2").prop("disabled")

$("#boton3").prop("disabled", true);

console.log('Estado del boton 1: ', valor1)
console.log('Estado del boton 2: ', valor2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton1"> Activado </button>
<button id="boton2" disabled> Desactivado </button>
<button id="boton3"> Me desactivaron </button>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[answer] y
[mre]

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso por qué el voto negativo?

Comment: La pregunta es bastante precisa, ¿cómo verificar la propiedad de disabled en un botón en javascript? Pero bueno... cada cual tiene su punto de vista.

Comment: Acá concuerdo con @JaimeMenéndez la pregunta se entiende, y si no lleva código es porque es bastante simple. Y que marques una respuesta con un voto negativo solo porque no te gustó la pregunta no tiene mucho sentido la verdad, en todo caso marca la pregunta con un voto negativo, porque objetivamente la respuesta está muy bien y completa, y cumple con los 2 links que le mandaste

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución @JaimeMenendez , para mantener la calidad en el sitio te sugerimos responder preguntas realizadas en base a [ask] o ayudar a el OP a mejorar su pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, para mí la pregunta estaba bastante clara pero ya veo que para otros no. Revisaré los links que me comentó. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer una función JS para verificar el estado del botón.

En el siguiente ejemplo muestro como verificar si el primer botón ("btn1") esta deshabilitado:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function VerificarBtn(btnId) {
    
        var btn = document.getElementById(btnId);
 
        if (btn.disabled==true) {
            alert("el boton esta deshabilitado")
        } else {
             alert("el boton esta habilitado")
        }
    };
</script>

<button id="btn1" disabled  class="button">BTN 1</button>

<button id="btn2"  onClick="VerificarBtn('btn1');" class="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[answer] y
[mre]

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso sería bueno justifiques tu voto negativo !!!

Comment: por que veo muy mal que respondas preguntas mal planteadas o que no cumplen con el criterio del sitio. en este caso el OP no ha demostrado el mínimo esfuerzo ... solo falto que colocara háganme la tarea.  no es nada precisa esa pregunta y esta mal planteada... primero que nada si vez pregunta por algo que no ha colocado ni por asomo el codigo html relacionado. segundo pregunta por JS y Coloca la etiqueta de JQuery y tu respuesta no incluye como se hace con Jquery en ese caso lo cual deja abierta la pregunta a especulaciones y respuestas basadas en opiniones. quieres que continúe?

Comment: @ErickCastillo , si Dev001 y tu son la misma persona te sugerimos evitar realizar votación entre las mismas cuentas, recuerda que esto no es permitido en el sitio ,ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483579/como-cerrar-autom%c3%a1ticamente-el-mensaje-bootstrap/483582#483582  Te sugerimos revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196 y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange

Comment: no he realizado votación en esta pregunta, ni a favor ni en contra de dev001, lo que vi fue que estaban votando en negativo ambas respuestas, y pues hay que valorar el tiempo que se toman para entender y descifrar algunas preguntas con el fin de poder ayudar.